# UWP SplitView: Push Content instead of shrink it on PaneOpen

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want the `SplitView` to push the content out of the window when the pane is opened, instead of shrinking it to still fit in the window. Another way to describe this would be, that I want the content to keep its width.

Thank you for time. I'm still in the very beginning of UWP development.

Comment: When the pane opens, the content part isn't shrunk to fit the window, the width of it is constant. The pane part is just overlaid on the content part. In addition, what does "push the content out of the window" mean? Can you show more details about you expected behavior?

Comment: I'll try to do a better job at explaining what I want: Let's say I have a StackPanel as content that has a red rectangle with the same width as the pane at the end. When the pane is open I want just that rectangle completely out of the screen, as opposed to having it displayed in reduced width.

Comment: You could try to set the DisplayMode of SplitView as 'Overlay', in this case, when open the pane, it will overlay the content area instead of reduce the width of content part to fit the available screen. The width of content part won't be changed. You can use it to see if it meets your needs.